# Edit DateTime to be relative to a different date

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is there a way using Azure ML to edit a column of DateTime values so that the dates are set relative to a different date, e.g. the min date in the data set?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of you experiment? or a sample of the data you need to manipulate?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. In AzureML, the data type used to describe the difference between two dates is called TimeSpan. You can create features of this type by subtracting dates from one another in an Execute Python/R Script module. Here is an example R script to subtract the minimum datetime in a column named "mydate" from each datetime value in that column:

```
df <- maml.mapInputPort(1)

df$mydate <- df$mydate - min(df$mydate)

maml.mapOutputPort("df");
```

When you visualize the output of this module, you will see that the "mydate" column is of type TimeSpan.